# Integrate a Database into a C# Application

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am trying to create an application that will utilize a database to write logs and save information etc. However, I haven't been able to wrap my head around the overall architecture of how the two would mesh together. I am using Visual Studio C# throughout this process.

**Here's how I would like this to work** - My company has a fileserver which is responsible for all the group policies on the network and everyone in the company. What I would like to try and do is have a DB that lives on the fileserver/network, and anyone running the application will utilize that database.

**Application Requirements** -

- Create New db Tables
- Add rows to db tables

**Here is where my confusion lies** - As of now, just playing around trying to figure things out, I have a C# Class Library with a Service-Based Database item. I can add tables, etc. Not a problem. My general issue is with the architecture of the two programs as a whole.

- So, a broad version of my question is what should handle what?
- i.e. If I want my application to add a new table to the database, what will handle that? The application or the database?

*Should I create helper functions in my Class Library that contains the db, and then utilize that class library in my application to call these helper functions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your database will be hosted on a network, I think database creation, table creation, view creation, stored procedure creation, etc... should be done in the database. The application should be responsible for querying the tables or views, and inserting and deleting rows from the appropriate tables.

The only time the application should create the tables and views and stored procedures is if you are using a distributed database (a database that gets distributed with your application and runs on the client's machine). Because the database won't exist on the client's machine, it is necessary to create the database structure before your application can use it. This, however, is not your scenario. Your database will be hosted on a network or shared drive.

As far as database engines to use, I recommend either [Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/) (Not free, but is the leader in database server engines) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) (GLP Licensed and is suitable for most scenarios).

Once you settle on a database engine, I recommend you use my [LayerGen 3.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000660/LayerGen). LayerGen will automatically create data and business layers for you in C# or VB.Net based off your database. It works with Microsoft SQL Server, MySql, SQLite, or MS Access. Once you have your database created, it will create code based off your tables and fields and create classes that allow you to easily access your database from your application.

Good luck!

Comment: The one thing that I have a question on is the database engine. I downloaded SQL Server data tools for Visual Studio. Is that a db engine, if not what is it? Otherwise, I am super lost on the point of these tools with Visual Studio. I can create a table, but then I have to save the `SQL` table somewhere - where would that be?.

Comment: @Adjit - That is not the database server. Those are just the tools to work with SQL Server. You can download a trial of SQL Server 2014 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2014). The trial is good for 180 days. If you want something free, try [MySQL Community Edition](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about this.

- 1) You could use entity framework that would allow you to create models in c# that would structure the database for you (migrations). It's fairly complicated to get started with this, but here is a good place to get started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx
- 2) You can go the more archaic route and create the database and talk to the database by writing your own sql commands http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/837599/Using-Csharp-to-connect-to-and-query-from-a-SQL-da

I strongly encourage the 1 as it's much easier to maintain